# Python: Rename multiple Image Files

Tags: python, image, rename

I need a program that I can tell what number to start at, then rename from there.

The twist is it has to keep the extension the same since there are both `JPG` and `PNG`, maybe even `GIF`.

So if I want to rename maybe 10k pics starting from "`a200`" I could.

The closest I've come is this:

```
import os

files = os.listdir('.')
index = 0
for filename in files:
    os.rename(filename, str(index).zfill(5)+ '.jpg')
    index += 1
```

Comment: BTW, you could do `for index, filename in enumerate(files):`.

Answer (score 7):

It's a good idea to have a dryrun option when doing file renamings, so you can see what would happen before making any changes that won't be so easy to reverse...

And you ought to check that the new name doesn't exist already.

```
import os

# Create a list of files from the current directory who's last 4 characters
# as lowercase are either '.jpg' or '.png'
files = [ f for f in os.listdir('.') if f[-4:].lower() in ('.jpg','.png') ]

DRYRUN=True

for (index,filename) in enumerate(files):
  extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
  newname = "picture-%05d%s" % (index,extension)
  if os.path.exists(newname):
    print "Cannot rename %s to %s, already exists" % (filename,newname)
    continue
  if DRYRUN:
    print "Would rename %s to %s" % (filename,newname)
  else:
    print "Renaming %s to %s" % (filename,newname)
    os.rename(filename,newname)
```

---

*Minor update*

If you wanted to preserve the current lexical order of the files, you'd just need to sort the initial file list:

```
files = sorted(f for f in os.listdir('.') if f[-4:].lower() in ('.jpg','.png'))
```

If you want anything more complicated, like extracting an existing index number from the filename and reformatting it, it would be best open another question.

Comment: Two small correstions: 1) `if f[-4:].lower()` 2) and the format string shall read: `"picture-%05d%s"`

Comment: I don't see my images got `rename`.

Comment: @Igwest : Thanks for correcting, without you this code is not even working at all. !

Comment: Thanks for this! I was wondering if it was possible to have it rename the jpgs 1 - x in the order the appear in the folder? e.g. when I run this I get `Would rename Picture 366.PNG to  1341.PNG` and I want it to be renammed 366